# Show that $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod{m}$ iff $i \equiv j \pmod{d}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I've been given the following problem to solve:

> Let $a$ be an integer and $m$ and $d$ natural numbers. Assume $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, and that $d$ is the smallest possible number for which this holds. In that case, show that $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod{m}$ if and only if $i \equiv j \pmod{d}$ for all natural numbers $i$ and $j$.

If we assume that $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ and $a^i \equiv a^j \pmod{m}$, then we can write
\begin{align}
mx = (a^d - 1) \\
my = (a^i - a^j)
\end{align} for some $x$ and $y$. But I don't seem to get anywhere by comparing these expressions for $m$.
If we assume $i \equiv j \pmod{d}$, then we may write 
\begin{align}
dz = (i-j) 
\end{align}
for some $z$. I can use this to make an expression for $i = dz +j$ and insert into $a^i$, but I don't seem to get anywhere there either.

I'm really confused by this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show only the non-trivial part of **iff.** From the definition of $d$ it follows that $a$ is invertible $\bmod m,\;$ so $a^{-j}\pmod m$ is defined. Assume without loss of generality that $i>j;\;$  then 
$$a^i=a^{j} \pmod m$$
implies 
$$1\equiv a^ia^{-j}\equiv a^{i-j}\pmod m$$
Therefore from the minimal property of $d\;$ it follows that $i-j$ is a multiple of $d,\;$ i.e. $i\equiv j \pmod  d$

Comment: What do you mean by $a^{-j} \pmod{m}$ is defined?

Comment: *Defined* means that you can multiply the congruence by $a^{-j}$. If $a^d\equiv 1$ then  $a$ is invertible and you have $a^{-j}\equiv (a^{-1})^j \pmod m.$ The step 
$$a^i \equiv a^{j} \pmod m \Longrightarrow 1\equiv a^ia^{-j}\equiv a^{i-j}\pmod m$$
is  generally not valid if $a$ is not invertible. E.g. $3^6 \equiv 3^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {15}$
but $3^{6-2}=3^4 \equiv 6 \pmod {15}$

Comment: So you mean that because $a$ is invertible modulo $m$, $a^{-j}$ must exist? And you use that to show that $a^{i-j}$ must be congruent to 1 modulo $m$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.